# Displaying Author Bio on single post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently finishing up work for a client website and I want the author bio to show up on the bottom of single posts. The only thing is, I only want this section to display on the front-end of the User Bio is filled in. I am so close to getting this to work, but for some reason the  in the following code isn't displaying on the front end when the bio section has copy within it.

```
<?php   
$author_bio     = the_author_meta('description'); 
if (!empty($author_bio)) :
?>  

<h3><?php _e('About', 'roots') ;?> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author() ;?></a>:</h3>
<?php echo '<p>', $author_bio, '</p>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
$author_bio     = the_author_meta('description');
```

with

```
$author_bio     = get_the_author_meta('description');
```

The function the_author_meta echo it's output instead of returning it.